# How can I apply Big-O notation to this algorithm?

Tags: python

I don't know how can I apply Big-O notation to distance problem code. Could you advise me?

```
from math import sqrt

a = [4, 2, 8, 5, 6, 2, 6]
b = [3, 6, 4, 7, 4, 3, 9]

choose = int(input("1.맨하탄 2.유클리드 번호를 입력하시오  "))

def euclidean_distance(x,y):
  return sqrt(sum(pow(q-p,2) for p,q in zip(x,y)))


def manhattan_distance(x,y):
  return sum(abs(p-q) for p,q in zip(x,y))


if 0 < choose < 2 :
  print(manhattan_distance(a,b))
elif 1 < choose < 3 :
  print(euclidean_distance(a,b))
else:
  print("Please input 1 or 2")
```

Comment: Just a remark: instead of `if 0 < choose < 2:` I would use `if choose == 1:`, and instead of `elif 1 < choose < 3:` I would use `elif  choose == 2:`

Comment: @oszkar I agree, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of your program is one simple loop over the array.

If you denote the array size as `N`, the complexity would be `O(N)`.